# Iwant to insert if condition inside the table->addrow in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iwant to insert this code

```
if($transaction_user_define_fields->udf_type == 'Selectbox'){
    echo '<i class="fa fa-list fa-lg text-primary pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View option" onclick="viewUDFOPT('.$transaction_user_define_fields->tran_udf_col_id.')"></i>';
}
```

inside

```
$this->table->add_row()
```

but im getting an error .please help

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: i encountered this error Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) ..

Comment: $this->table->add_row( if($transaction_user_define_fields->udf_type == 'Selectbox'){echo '<i class="fa fa-list fa-lg text-primary pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View option" onclick="viewUDFOPT('.$transaction_user_define_fields->tran_udf_col_id.')"></i>'; );

Comment: show your entire code pls (and edit your question properly - there is no need to copy that in a comment) - because imo this doesn't make any sense

Comment: okay .sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($transaction_user_define_fields->udf_type == 'Selectbox'){
       $this->table->add_row('<i class="fa fa-list fa-lg text-primary pull-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View option" onclick="viewUDFOPT('.$transaction_user_define_fields->tran_udf_col_id.')"></i>');
   }
```

This would make the  tag clickable, if you want to make the entire cell clickable you will have to set it as a param in add row
as per codeigniter documentation

```
 $cell = array('data' => 'Blue', 'class' => 'highlight', 'colspan' => 2);
 $this->table->add_row($cell, 'Red', 'Green');
 // generates
 // <td class='highlight' colspan='2'>Blue</td><td>Red</td><td>Green</td>
```